# Extraer fecha dentro de una cadena de texto POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una columna con comentarios y fecha de entrega juntos, ej:

[image: Texto]

**[EDIT](Tambien tengo fechas con formato 01/01/2020, osea con 4 digitos en el año)**

Quiero saber si hay una función como PATINDEX para poder extraer la fecha independientemente de la posición de la fecha dentro del string

Mi objetivo es separar las fechas y agregarlo a una nueva columna separada del comentario

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: búscala como expresión  regular

Answer (score 0):

Como yo lo veo el problema se puede solucionar simulando la función PATINDEX de SQL Server en PostgreSQL simplemente con copiando una de las tantas funciones que se encuentran en Google.

Por tanto, inicia creando una función denominada `patindex`:

```sql
CREATE
OR
replace
FUNCTION "patindex"( "pattern"   VARCHAR,
                    "expression" VARCHAR ) returns INT
AS
  $body$
  SELECT coalesce( strpos( $2 ,
         (
                SELECT ( regexp_matches( $2 ,'('
                              || replace( replace( trim( $1, '%' ), '%', '.*?' ), '_', '.' )
                              || ')' ,'i' ) )[ 1 ] limit 1 ) ) ,0 ) ;
  
  $body$ LANGUAGE 'sql' immutable;
```

Tras ello surgen varias casuísticas y dudas que personalmente se me presentan:

- ¿Qué pasa si la fecha no se encuentra siempre al final de la cadena? ¿Es posible?
- ¿La fecha siempre podrá ser identificada con el slash `/` o puede tener otro separador como el guíon `-`?

Pero, solo en caso que la fecha siempre sea lo último en la cadena y que se encuentre separada siempre por el slash `/`, entonces lo siguiente te funcionaría:

```sql
with ejemplo(cadena) as (values('ejemplo 11/01/2011'), ('otro ejemplo sin nada'),
  ('ultimo ejemplo 11/09/2018'))

select cadena,  
  case when patindex('%/%', cadena) > 0 
  then substring(cadena,patindex('%/%', cadena)-2, length(cadena))
  else null
  end soloFecha
from ejemplo
```

> El CTE no lo tomes en cuenta solo fue para poder replicar el ejemplo.

Lo que tienes aquí es un `CASE...WHEN` simple, lo que hace es llamar a la función que hemos creado anteriormente denominada `patindex` y buscar desde que índice en la cadena inicia, en caso que no tenga el slash `/` la respuesta será cero (0).

Finalmente, usamos `substring` restándole dos índices, esto porque las fechas inician con dos caracteres simulando a los dos dígitos en las fechas (considere esto otra suposición); tras ello lo único que queda es colocar ¿hasta dónde extraerá la cadena?... considerando que la fecha es lo último en la cadena, la pregunta anterior se responde usando  `length`.

La respuesta quedaría similar a esto:

```sql
+---------------------------+------------+
| cadena                    | soloFecha  |
+---------------------------+------------+
| ejemplo 11/01/2011        | 11/01/2011 |
| otro ejemplo sin nada     | null       |
| ultimo ejemplo 11/09/2018 | 11/09/2018 |
+---------------------------+------------+
```

> Por último, te dejo la <kbd>[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/8tXfwtn1)</kbd> para que puedas probar tu mismo.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias! si, me falto poner info.
La fecha puede estar de muchas formas variables ya que se carga a mano, puede ser 01/10/2022 como puede ser 1/10/2022 o 1/10/22.  estuve intentando otras opciones buscandola como expresion regular usando substring('%#"__/%%/__#"%' for '#' )